# ItemDataBound not firing

Tags: c#, asp.net

For some reason my itemdatabound on my repeater just isn't firing. I can't work out why. Heres what I have; (Removed unnecessary stuff)

**C# page code :**

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            load_Repeater();
        }

        private void load_Repeater()
        {
            dtLocations = new components.db.PIDSDB.SubPIDLocationsItemsDataTable();
            dtLocations = taLocations.GetLocationsByProductsAndSPID('1', Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["SPID"]));

            rptFire.DataSource = dtLocations;
            rptFire.DataBind();

        }

        protected void rptFire_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
        {

            DataRowView nRow = null;

            switch (e.Item.ItemType)
            {
                case ListItemType.Item:
                case ListItemType.AlternatingItem:
                Int32 sqrmtr = Convert.ToInt32(nRow["LocationSqrMtr"].ToString());
                Int32 mypence = Convert.ToInt32(nRow["PricePerItem"].ToString());
                Int32 mandays = Convert.ToInt32(nRow["ManDayPerItem"].ToString());

                ((Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblName")).Text = "" + nRow["LocationName"];
                ((Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblArea")).Text = "" + nRow["LocationSqrMtr"];
                ((Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblCharge")).Text = ""+ Functions.MultiplyNumbers(sqrmtr, mypence);
                ((Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblPence")).Text = "" + nRow["PricePerItem"];
                ((Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblManDays")).Text = "" + Functions.MultiplyNumbers(sqrmtr, mandays);
                ((Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblCosts")).Text = "WORK OUT";
                ((Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblMargin")).Text = "WORK OUT";

                    break;
            }
        }
```

**In .aspx page repeater code:**

```
   <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptFire" OnItemDataBound="rptFire_ItemDataBound">
       <ItemTemplate>
          <tr>
              <td><asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblName"></asp:Label></td>
              <td><asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblArea"></asp:Label></td>
              <td><asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblCharge"></asp:Label></td>
              <td><asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblPence"></asp:Label></td>
               <td><asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblManDays"></asp:Label></td>
               <td><asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblCosts"></asp:Label></td>
               <td><asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblMargin"></asp:Label></td>
            </tr>
          </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
```

The datasource and databind code runs just not the itemdatabound

Comment: What type returns taLocations.GetLocationsByProductsAndSPID method and are there any items in it?

Comment: When I do preview data on the typed dataset using the same variables I get 4 back

Comment: Have tried to debug the code??

Comment: Just curious, Why are you initializing **dtLocations** twice in `dtLocations = new` and `dtLocations = taLocations`. If they are *typed dataset* try `rptFire.DataSource = dtLocations.Tables["YourTableName"];`

Comment: If you're sure the data source isn't null or empty in this case, I'm pretty sure it's something outside of your code snippets that's causing this issue for you. Nothing there, as far as I can see, would be preventing the ItemDataBound event handler from being called.

Answer (score 3):

You might be missing `AutoEventWireup=true` in Page header in aspx file.

**Edit:**
If buttons handlers do work, perhaps it's problem with databinging - are you sure you are calling `DataBind` on `MyRepeater` or any of it's parent control? If you are calling `DataBind` manually, does it depend on `Page.IsPostBack` on your page?

ItemDataBound will fire only during DataBinding. If you do a DataBind on PostBack, it should fire. However, DataBind doesn't happen automatically on PostBack. (Instead, Repeater will rebuild from ViewState.) If there is no dependency on data, you should consider using the ItemCreated event instead. That will fire when building the Repeater, no matter whether that is during DataBind or from ViewState.